# How do I 'revert to inherited' if control is not clickable?

Tags: delphi, visual-inheritance

Assume the following situation:

- `FrmBase` has a `TPanel` named `PnlClient`, align `alClient`
- `FrmDescendant` inherits from `FrmBase`
- In `FrmDescendant` I change a `PnlClient` property
- In `FrmDescendant` I place another control (say another `TPanel` named `PnlDescendant`) on `PnlClient` and align it `alClient`.
  `PnlDescendant` now completely covers `PnlClient`
- I place lots of other components on `PnlDescendant`, not necessarily aligned, so I'm afraid to change `PnlDescendant` (e.g. setting align to `alNone` and resizing) and lose positions

How can I execute 'revert to inherited' for `PnlClient`?
There's nothing in the main menu, or in the popup menu for the controls in the Structure View...

Currently using Delphi 10.4.1 Sydney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy for a keyboard user like myself:

1. Click on `PnlDescendant` in the form editor to make it the focused and selected control.
2. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to select its parent, `PnlClient`.
3. Press the [Menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) on your keyboard to display the context menu of `PnlClient`. If you have a cheap keyboard without a Menu key, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> instead.
4. Click on "Revert to Inherited". (Or, much faster: press the menu item's underlined character, probably <kbd>I</kbd>.)
5. (But notice that this will remove `PnlDescendant` completely. Probably you didn't want that, but that's how it works.)

Comment: In other setups, you might also use the Tab key to move between sibling controls. You can see in the **Structure** tree view which one is currently focused. Tab your way through to the right one and press the Menu key (or Shift+F10).

Comment: The *menu* key! Wow, I have never used that ;-)

Comment: And thanks for mentioning point 5. It was not a good example in the question.

Comment: Actually, I use it almost daily (for instance, when I typeset mathematical formulae in Microsoft Word).